# Incorrect datetime value: '2018-03-00' for column 'created_date' at row 1

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

Hi guys i am running this query

```
DELETE FROM us_current WHERE created_date > '2018-03-00';
```

and it is showing me the following error and stopping the execution

[image]

my table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `us_current` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(2) DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '1 - active, 0 - inactive',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=113933 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

Comment: try changing it to ">= '2018-03-01';"

Comment: Yes it worked out thanks @Aaron but could you give me some explanation too thanks

Comment: oh because 00 is not a valid day ?

Comment: Exactly right. Has to be able to compare it, and since the column is declared as a datetime, it needs to be a valid datetime

Comment: @Aaron please put your comment as an answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
DELETE FROM us_current WHERE created_date >= '2018-03-01';
```